# Useful maven plugins

Tags: maven-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best “General Purpose” Maven plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2616397/best-general-purpose-maven-plugins)

Which are some of the most useful (and maybe not so well-known) maven plugins that you've used? Time and time again during development I stumble upon a plugin through Google that makes my life a lot easier and I didn't know existed.

Here are a couple I just used recently:

1. [YUI compressor plugin](http://alchim.sourceforge.net/yuicompressor-maven-plugin/)
2. [Build number generator plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/)
3. [Jetty plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Maven+Jetty+Plugin/) , very useful when functional tests are part of the build.
4. [License plugin](http://code.google.com/p/maven-license-plugin/) , for managing and enforcing source licenses

Answer (score 0):

I like [Sonar](http://www.sonarsource.org/) which is more than just a plugin. It offers a complete dashboard and overview of several code quality metrics.

Answer (score 0):

1. DBUnit plugin
2. Cobertura plugin
3. Cargo plugin
4. Tomcat plugin